# How to add 2 columns in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table called "attendance" in which there are several columns.

I want to add 2 columns and put the result in the third column in the same table.

How to do it in Mysql?

I want it to happen every time when ever a new entry comes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED:** If you have no control over `INSERT` statements and you want your calculated column values to be persisted then you can use a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_bi_attendance
BEFORE INSERT ON attendance
FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.column3 = NEW.column1 + NEW.column2;
```

*Note: you probably have to cover a case when values in `column1` and/or `column2` are being updated. Use a separate `BEFORE UPDATE`trigger for that.*

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_bu_attendance
BEFORE UPDATE ON attendance
FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.column3 = NEW.column1 + NEW.column2;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/411fe/1)** demo

---

Otherwise just calculate it on the fly in `SELECT` clause

```
SELECT column1, column2, column1 + column2 column3
  FROM attendance
```

or create a view

```
CREATE VIEW vw_attendance AS
SELECT column1, column2, column1 + column2 column3
  FROM attendance
```

---

To update rows that are already in the table use `UPDATE`

```
UPDATE attendance
   SET column3 = column1 + column2
```